# Form password field in iframe behave as if empty when filled automatically by Chrome

Tags: django, forms, google-chrome, django-allauth

When Google chrome auto-fills the password field with saved credentials info and that I submit the form, the data for the password is an empty string.

Because of this I get a "field is required" kind of error, even thought there is something in the field.

[image]

I am using django-allauth but I did some test and the issue seems to also happen when I use basic django Forms.

Any idea what could cause the issue? Ultimately, I could just try to deactivate the auto-populate for this field but I'd rather not.

Note that it behaves properly on firefox, which doesn't populate the field on page load but only when the user select his username in an autocomplete dropdown menu.

EDIT - More info: I found that that this is linked to my form being inside an iframe. When I display it directly on the main page, this issue doesn't happen. I still need to make it work within an iframe though...

EDIT2: After doing some research, it seems to be a bug with chrome not sending the proper events on an iframe that is added dynamically:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669045

https://codereview.chromium.org/2603623002

I'm trying to find a work-around....

Answer (score 0):

use javascript on load page to set value of input = innerhtml.

for example goto facebook.com and open console and write:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
```

you will need to set email input value to

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? innerhtml of what?

Comment: for example go to facebook.com and open console and write: document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value

Comment: you will need to make value of email input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value

Comment: I just tried it, but the innerHtml is also an empty string. (NB: its value is also an empty string)

Comment: I edited my question. I found out that this happens only when my form is in an iframe. Not when it is on the main page. I still need it to work in an iframe however...